# Scrolling in Android Studio with laptop touchpad sometimes doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I've had this issue for a while now, with absolutely no mention of it anywhere.

The problem is that, most of the times, I can't scroll through my editor using the two finger gesture (I'm using Windows 10).

Also, sometimes, it can scroll but with the zooming pinch. (Weird, huh?)

Further info:
OS: Windows 10 x64
Laptop: Lenovo Z50
Android Studio Version: 2.3.3

P.S: When I connect an external mouse, it works just fine. And this problem only exists inside Android Studio

Comment: Android studio version?

Comment: 2.3.3 (As mentioned in the post)

Comment: never experienced on 2.3.3, can you take a look at preview version?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what that is

Comment: refer https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/index.html

Comment: I'm faced with same issue. You already solved it?

Comment: so what does pinch-to-zoom do from the mouse?  What does the two-finger function do from the mouse?  Unless you have an Apple Magic Mouse, your mouse doesn't do that, so i'm not sure what you mean when you say it works fine from the mouse.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue with my lenovo laptop, all I did was minimized all open application and refreshd window you can say the desktop where you see your wallpaper(Right click on window(HomeScreen)) and click refresh) in my case I used Fn+F5 and it solved my issue.

Comment: Sorry, I dont know any other solution.

Comment: quite amazingly refreshing actually works !! , don't know why ? , but it does work

Answer (score 0):

It sounds strange, but true. I was facing issue in Android studio arctic fox patch 3. Whenever I opened Excel in my laptop, if I scroll in studio, it was scrolling in Excel. Just check if you have opened any applications which involves scrolling(it my case the culprit was Office Excel).